# Debugging Delphi Application on Non Development Environment

Tags: delphi, debugging, windbg

I am attempting to use WinDBG or another debugger to debug a CodeGear Delphi 2007 Windows application on a remote machine. I have been unable to produce symbol files for WinDBG.

Is there a way to use WinDBG or another debugger to debug Delphi applications on a system that doesn't include the IDE?

**Edit1**

The remote debugger is not an option here. I am able to remote in to the end user PC, but I am unable to use the remote debugger due to firewall restrictions.

**Edit2**

I am able to remote in to the machine, but can not connect the CodeGear remote debugger due to firewall restrictions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about the remote debugger?  Build your app with remote debug symbols and debug from your development machine across the network.

Comment: I would love to be able to do this, but regretfully the other machine is on a completely different network with firewall restrictions.

Comment: I have been able to remote in to the PC, but I am unable to connect the Remote Debugger through TCP\IP. I was looking at something similar to WinDBG to troubleshoot the application through the GUI since I can't directly connect the debugger.

Comment: If you can't connect remotely, then I like X-Ray's idea.  madExcept rocks.

Answer (score 5):

instead, i rely on MadExcept stack tracing and some logging features.  my application is distributed worldwide & this has been sufficient.

Comment: I looked in to this product a little more and I'm pretty impressed with what it can do! Regretfully, the application isn't crashing. I'm needing a way to dump the memory or walk the application to catch a more logical error occurring. Thank you for the interesting product though!

Answer (score 4):

You can try generating a map file and then convert it to a dbg file using map2dbg from 
http://code.google.com/p/map2dbg/

Then you can load the dbg file in WinDbg.

Disclaimer: I had faced a similar issue but I managed to do remote debugging and didn't have to do all this. So I am not sure this will work. But if you try it then do let us know if it works.

Comment: I looked in to this quite a bit yesterday and discovered that it isn't compatible with Delphi yet. If you've got any more information on it, this would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is one more of those "I don't have an actual answer" answers, but it *might* just help...

Have you considered adding logging to your application? I've heard great things about [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/products/smartinspect/). With it, you can log all sorts of information, including stack traces and "watches" (variables).

Another logging product for Delphi is [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/).

Comment: I can confirm that SmartInspect is a very reliable solution. Ok, you cannot singlestep debug with it the logging is very good and advanced.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi you could use Run -> Attach to Process, select the remote machine and select the process you'd like to debug.

Comment: ... asuming the target machine is running the remote debugger.

Comment: I've never used this "procedure" so I didn't think of it. Thx for setting it straight, at least "I"'ve learned something.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tds2dbg/ can be used to convert Delphi's TDS debug files to DBG files. This gives basic symbol information -- functions, classes, units, but not variables. Enough for a reasonable call stack, and with a bit of knowledge, enough to debug Delphi apps live and with dumps.

I've written about some of Delphi+WinDBG experiences on my blog: https://marc.durdin.net/2015/11/windbg-and-delphi-a-collection-of-posts/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the great suggestions and interesting products.

To solve this specific issue, the "best" way I found uses the *OutputDebugString* located in the *Windows* namespace. This, along with [Debug View from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx), will allow me to gather debug information and sort through it pretty quickly.

If you decide to use this method, make sure everything is wrapped in ANSI formatting. IE:

```
OutputDebugString(PAnsiChar(string1 + string2));
```

This makes sure that string1 and string2 are combined and then converted in to ANSI Characters.

I probably should have just started dumping text to a file for something quick and dirty, but this will allow a non-debugging version to emit debugging messages.

Comment: I want to leave this question open for a few more days to see if we can't get a better answer than this to actually connect the debugger.